# Is it NOT possible to 'nest' ResultSet queries? or use a query inside a loop?

Tags: java, sqlite, while-loop, resultset

```
public void generateEnumeration() {
        StyledDocument docExam = txtpaneExamGeneration.getStyledDocument();
        StyledDocument docAnsKey = txtpaneAnswerKey.getStyledDocument();

        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sql_items.sqlite");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT group_name FROM active_items;");
            int num = numIndex;
            char[] letterArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
            int letterIndex = 0;

            docExam.insertString(docExam.getLength(), "Enumeration - Enumerate the following:\n\n" , null);

            while(rs.next()){
                String groupNameHandler = rs.getString("group_name");

                docExam.insertString(docExam.getLength(), letterArray[letterIndex] + ". " + groupNameHandler + ".\n", null);

                ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM active_items WHERE group_name = '" + groupNameHandler + "'");
                while(rs2.next()) {
                    String itemNumbering = Integer.toString(num);
                    String ansHandler = rs.getString("item_name");

                    docAnsKey.insertString(docAnsKey.getLength(), itemNumbering + ". ", null);
                    docAnsKey.insertString(docAnsKey.getLength(), ansHandler + "\n", null);

                    num ++; // this is needed to increase the numbering while in the WHILE LOOP
                    numIndex ++; // this is needed to save the last number used after the WHILE LOOP so that it will be continued on the next function
                } // end for ResultSet 2

                letterIndex ++;

            } // end ResultSet 1

            letterIndex = 0;
            docExam.insertString(docExam.getLength(), "\n\n" , null);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(generateExam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(generateExam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

the purpose of this code is to generate an Enumeration-Type Quiz. This will output into 2 JTextPanes, one for the `docExam` and one for the `docAnsKey`

`ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT group_name FROM active_items;");` should (and it does, becase I tested on SQLite and it works) retrieve 3 Rows from the database. However, the output goes like this:

```
docExam:

Enumeration - Enumerate the following

A. Enum question 1
```

and

```
in docAnsKey:

1. CorrectAns1
2. CorrectAns2
```

when in reality, the database have 12 Items in it.

It seems like `while(rs.next()){` is only executed once, that's why the rest of the code is skipped. And I can't find where is my error here. Can somebody please point it out to me?

Content of the Database:

```
item_id --- item_name    --- group_name
1            CorrectAns1     Enum question 1
2            CorrectAns2     Enum question 1
3            CorrectAns3     Enum question 2
4            CorrectAns4     Enum question 2
5            CorrectAns5     Enum question 2
6            CorrectAns6     Enum question 2
7            CorrectAns7     Enum question 2
8            CorrectAns8     Enum question 2
9            CorrectAns9     Enum question 2
10           CorrectAns10    Enum question 2
11           CorrectAns11    Enum question 3
12           CorrectAns12    Enum question 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours trials and errors, I conclude that ResultSet cannot handle multiple 'uses'. So when I used it for `rs2.next()`, it forgot the data from `rs.next()`. So my workaround is to put the entire 2nd portion of the function out from the while loop, since the ordering is similar to when I call `SELECT DISTINCT group_name FROM active_items;` and `SELECT * FROM active_items` and would not affect the integrity of the program.

final code here:

```
public void generateEnumeration() {
        StyledDocument docExam = txtpaneExamGeneration.getStyledDocument();
        StyledDocument docAnsKey = txtpaneAnswerKey.getStyledDocument();

        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sql_items.sqlite");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT group_name FROM active_items;");
            int num = numIndex;
            char[] letterArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
            int letterIndex = 0;

            docExam.insertString(docExam.getLength(), "Enumeration - Enumerate the following:\n\n" , null);

            while(rs.next()){
                String groupNameHandler = rs.getString("group_name");

                docExam.insertString(docExam.getLength(), letterArray[letterIndex] + ". " + groupNameHandler + ".\n", null);

                letterIndex ++;
            }

            ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM active_items");
            while(rs2.next()) {
                String itemNumbering = Integer.toString(num);
                String ansHandler = rs.getString("item_name");

                docAnsKey.insertString(docAnsKey.getLength(), itemNumbering + ". ", null);
                docAnsKey.insertString(docAnsKey.getLength(), ansHandler + "\n", null);

                num ++; // this is needed to increase the numbering while in the WHILE LOOP
                numIndex ++; // this is needed to save the last number used after the WHILE LOOP so that it will be continued on the next function
            }

            letterIndex = 0;
            docExam.insertString(docExam.getLength(), "\n\n" , null);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(generateExam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(generateExam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```